# Google Maps APi for iOS: UIActivityView on custom info window

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to put a spinner inside a custom info window that appears when the user presses a marker.  I have a custom view for the window that has lots of subviews that show up fine.  But when I try to add a UIActivityView or an animated PNG sequence, that doesn't show. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: There is not enough information here, the title mentions Google Maps API but there's nothing in your main post. Could you be clearer about what's not working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#a961e81669891377c9ebee752ce53340f) on the `mapView:markerInfoWindow:` method says:

> If you change this view after this method is called, those changes
>   will not necessarily be reflected in the rendered version.

It seems likely that the Google map is not showing the actual `UIView` you return, but a screenshot of it taken when the info window is returned by the delegate.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213049/add-buttons-to-view-returned-by-markerinfowindow-delegate-method), this is made explicit in the [Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows) - it seems likely that the Android and iOS SDKs work similarly.

If you've changed the view I'm not sure if there is a way to force the SDK to take a new screenshot of it. Possibly you could try setting the map's selected marker to nil and then back to your marker, to see if it then calls `mapView:markerInfoWindow:` again - although it might also re-centre the marker on the map when you do that. It also likely wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: I've been trying to call the method again...nothing works.  I tried performSelector, mapping the marker all over again...nothing calls the markerInfoWindow method.  Anyone figure out how to redraw the infoWindow?

Comment: You need the maps SDK to call `mapView:markerInfoWindow:` - calling it yourself, either directly or with `performSelector`, isn't going to do anything. How did you 'map the marker all over again'? (This might be best put in a separate question). If setting `map.selectedMarker` to nil and then back to your marker doesn't work, you could maybe try setting it to nil and then back to your marker after some short delay (eg using `dispatch_after`). This will cause the info window to flicker though.

Answer (score 0):

You can call mapView:markerInfoWindow: then inside the method you can create a UIView which you can add different controls on that UIView including the spinner. You can also specify on which location you would like to put the defined control.