# Google map marker with button action in objective c

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a google map with customised marker using UIView. I want to add a button on that UIView and add an action for that button. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoring to the documentation it doesn't seem that it can be done. If you see the [Google-Map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#info_windows). It says:

> Note: The info window is rendered as an image each time it is
>   displayed on the map.

Hence, it limits the interaction with the marker's infoWindow. You can just set an action to it. You can detect a tap on infoWindow and go to a different window using `didTapWindowOfMarker`.

See this thread: [Add buttons to view returned by markerInfoWindow delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213049/add-buttons-to-view-returned-by-markerinfowindow-delegate-method)

**Note: There is a feature request in Google's issue tracker to add direct support for this.** There are few solutions given on this [thread: Enhanced customization in the info window](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4961) which might help.