# How to add button on custom markerinfowindow with google map in swift2?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places, swift2

I need to add a button in markerinfowindow to navigate the user from current location to searched near by police station address...i found some answers in objective c...can any one please explain me that how to implement that in swift? i found the answer in objective c from the following link
[Add buttons to view returned by markerInfoWindow delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213049/add-buttons-to-view-returned-by-markerinfowindow-delegate-method)

Comment: put the break point and check the button is called or not in every click

Comment: Its not calling itself @Anbu,Karthik

Comment: then delete the connection and generate and try once

Comment: @Andu.karthik, I went through some answers,according to that that is problem with xcode 7.3 version itself....is it so?

Comment: Is there any another method is there to implement button action in Xib file?

Comment: can you send ur project I will check

Comment: how can i share my entire code? @Anbu.karthik

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you give me your mail id yar?so i wil share my file

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the button is at the top in your view hierarchy. If you have placed any views above the button then the `Button` action won't work.

Comment: i checked the hierarchy also,

Comment: @shilparamesh can you please show the screenshot of your nib file?