# Display Group Marker in Google Map - Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

How to display multiple marker nearest to 100 meter in Group Maker and show it on Google Map? Chat icon is a button and it will open chat screen for that user. Is it possible or not? Please help.

**Desired Output:**

[image: Group Marker with 3 location near to 100 meter]

I have implemented the single marker with custom window having button:

[image: Marker with custom window with button]

But after trying a lot, I am not able make group marker. If there is any trick to implement it let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you groupe the marker ??   . please provide the related  code ..

Comment: I have implemented single marker. not able to make group marker @scaisEdge

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40681031/3933302 
@scaisEdge

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript Code:**

Assuming you have an array for each group

```
  var groupMarkers  = [];
```

for each group you should populate the array with the related  marker

```
   groupMarkers.push(aGroupMembeMarker);
```

then you can show or hide the marker for the group iterating  over the array with a for loop eg:

```
   groupMarkers[i].setMap(map);  // for show the markers
```

or

```
  groupMarkers[i].setMap(null);  // for hide the markers
```

Comment: no ..i'm sorry   . i have not noted your ios  ..flag  .. this code is  is javascript but essentially is a pseudo code and then the  concept  is pratically the same  ...

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help & effort